# Apply multiple count conditionally in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `task` table which contains some `DateTime` type columns like completed, pending, exception. It joins `user` table and I want to bring
`userName, AllTaskCount, AllPendingTaskCount, AllCompletedTaskCount, AllExceptionTaskCount`.

If `Completed` columns has value than it will be considered as completed task, while if `completed` column is null with value in `exception` column then it is ExceptionTask and if neither `Completed` column has value nor `exception` one than it is pending task.

So I want to apply multiple count conditionally on above given condition. Please help...

Comment: Please provide the table schema and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CTEs`to get the result.

```
WITH Result AS(
    SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS AllTasksCount
     FROM User U
    JOIN TASK T ON U.Id = T.UserId
),PendingTasks AS (
    SELECT [NAme], COUNT(1) AS AllPendingTaskCount FROM Result
    WHERE Completed IS NULL and Exception IS NULL
    GROUP BY [Name]
),CompletedTasks AS (
    SELECT [NAme], COUNT(1) AS AllCompletedTaskCount FROM Result
    WHERE Completed IS NOT NULL and Exception IS NULL
    GROUP BY [Name]
),ExceptionTasks AS (
    SELECT [NAme], COUNT(1) AS AllExecptionTaskCount FROM Result
    WHERE Completed IS NULL and Exception IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY [Name]
)
SELECT DISTINCT R.[Name]
      ,AllTasksCount
      ,AllPendingTaskCount
      ,AllCompletedTaskCount
      ,AllExecptionTaskCount
FROM Result R
JOIN PendingTasks PT 
  ON PT.[Name] = R.[Name]
JOIN CompletedTasks CT 
  ON CT.[Name] = R.[Name]
JOIN ExceptionTasks ET 
  ON ET.[Name] = R.[Name]
```

Added sample schema and data. Please update it as per your requirements.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a6c59/1)